# $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(1+i)^n}{n^2}$ is divergent, and no idea about $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(3+4i)^n}{5^n\,\sqrt[999]{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

How can one see that $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(1+i)^n}{n^2}$ is divergent, and by which criterion? I was using a binomial theorem for $ (1+i)^n $ as $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dbinom{n}{k} i^n$, but it seems to get very complicated and not clear for me.

Question 2:
What is the result in this case: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(3+4i)^n}{5^n\,\sqrt[999]{n}}$?
The root criterion gives me 1 in this case...

Comment: summation over $i$, not $n$?

Comment: When you have two questions, it is better to post them separately.

Comment: The appearance of $(3+4i)/5$ makes me suspect that $i=\sqrt{-1}$.  If that's the case, it might help to say so, since $i$ is often used as an index of summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is $i$ the square root of $-1$ ?In any case the ratio test works,

$$\left | \frac{(1+i)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2} / \frac{(1+i)^{n}}{n^2} \right| =\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} |1+i|\rightarrow |1+i| $$
so as long as $1< |1+i| $ the series diverges.

For question 2 use Leibniz criteria. The sequence $\frac{1}{\sqrt[999]{n}}$ is decreasing and now you only have to show that

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^k \frac{(3+4i)^n}{5^n}$$ is bounded.
This can be done using the sum of a geometric series,

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^k r^n=\frac{r^{k+1}-1}{r-1}$$

So $$\left| \frac{r^{k+1}-1}{r-1}\right| \leq \frac{|r|^{k+1}+1}{|r-1|}$$

Now in our case $r=\frac{3+4i}{5}$ so $|r|=1$ and $|r-1|=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$
so in fact 
$$\left|\sum\limits_{n=1}^k r^n\right|\leq \sqrt{5}$$

Comment: Hello Rene, and thank you for the answer,
how should I proove, that the series is bounded?
I clearly see, that the absolute value of a sequence term is 1, so the sequence is for sure bounded, but in the series we have infinitely many different kind of positive and negative terms..
Greetings

Comment: I have added this to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

compute $|1+i|$ it is greater than one and so the terms of your series do not converge to $0$ hence the series is not convergent

Answer (score 1):

**If $n >0$** then, as $(1+i) \to \infty$ we have $(1+i)^n \to \infty$.

Therefore 
$$\lim_{i \to \infty}\frac{(1+i)^n}{n^2}=\infty \neq 0$$

**If $n <0$** then 
$$0 < \frac{(1+i)^n}{n^2}<\frac{1}{n^2}$$

The series is not defined if $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is for your second sum:

$$|3+4i|=5$$

$$\arg(3+4i)=\arctan(4/3)=:\alpha \approx 1$$

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(3+4i)^n}{5^n\,\sqrt[999]{n}} =
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\exp(\alpha n i)}{\sqrt[999]{n}}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[999]{n}} \downarrow 0$$

I'm pretty much certain that this sum will converge by something like Leibniz' alternating series test, but this is not exactly an alternating series so I can't say 100%.